# Read a Text File and Populate an Array

Tags: c#, file-io

I am to read a file and populate a String array. My data is like:

> Accident.
>   An unplanned event, unexpected and undesigned, which occurs suddenly and at a definite place.
>
> Accident Frequency.
>   The rate of the occurrence of accidents, often expressed in terms of the number of accidents over a period of time. It is one method used for measuring the effectiveness of loss prevention services. Contrast with Accident Severity.
>
> Accident Prevention.
>   See Loss Prevention Service.
>
> Accident Severity.
>   A measure of the severity or seriousness of losses, rather than the number of losses. It is measured in terms of time lost from work rather than the number of individual accidents. It is another way of measuring the effectiveness of loss prevention services. Contrast with Accident Frequency.

My code is:

```
private void openfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (text.Text == String.Empty)
    {
        err.SetError(text, "Needs to contain Text");
    }

    DialogResult result = open_dialog.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            string file_name = open_dialog.FileName;
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(file_name);

            String line;
            String[] wordslist=new String[count];

            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(file_name))
            {
                // read each line, ensuring not null (EOF)
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line == String.Empty)
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        wordslist = line.Split(' ');
                        count += 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i=0;i<wordslist.Length;i++)
            {
                //if (str==(text.Text))
                //{
                    //var index = Array.FindIndex(wordslist, row => row.Contains(text.Text));
                    Console.WriteLine("\ncapacity " + wordslist[i]);
                    //Console.WriteLine("\n" + wordslist[index - 1]+" capacity");
               //}

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nERROR= " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I simply want to print the contents of the array being populated with the file contents but the array is not being populated. But when I remove the Blank lines between my data the array will be populated with some few lines and I'm able to print some but not ALL contents.

The problem is that my data is so large that I can't remove lines and don't want to be! Is there any solution so that i can do this thing correctly?

Comment: That's because you are replacing already read word with new words for each line. Instead of `wordslist = line.Split(' ');` try and add result of line.split to the list instead of replacing it

Comment: what do you mean I am not getting you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void openfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (text.Text == String.Empty) {
        err.SetError(text, "Needs to contain Text");
    }

    DialogResult result = open_dialog.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            string file_name = open_dialog.FileName;
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(file_name);

            String line;
            List<string> wordslist=new List<string>(count);

            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(file_name))
            {
                // read each line, ensuring not null (EOF)
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line != String.Empty) {
                        // Here instead of replacing array with new content
                        // we add new words to already existing list of strings
                        wordslist.AddRange(line.Split(' '));
                        count += 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Count instead of Length because we're using List<T> now
            for (int i=0;i<wordslist.Count;i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\ncapacity " + wordslist[i]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nERROR= " + ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: yes you give an idea for +1 except for (int i=0;i<wordslist.Length;i++) should be for (int i=0;i<wordslist.Count;i++)

Comment: @user3154778 this answer solves your main problem however it still continues to use `count` which simply has no place in your code. It is a useless variable that does nothing more than make your code perform worse.

Comment: yes but when you're using an array list it should use ArrayList.Count not ArrayList.Length! my comment was about this anyhow thanks

Comment: @evanmcdonnal maybe he defines `count` outside of given method, then this is very useful as List size so that it does not have to resize in mid of run.

Answer (score 2):

There is a combination of issues. Firstly this line;

```
  String[] wordslist=new String[count];
```

That does nothing. It creates an array of length zero and sets the wordslist reference to that.

Then this is the real problem;

```
   wordslist = line.Split(' ');
```

`Split` returns a new string array, it doesn't add to the current one. You only get the final line because `wordslist` gets set to the result of calling split on that line in the last iteration of the loop. You can fix your code by doing;

```
  List<string> wordslist = new List<string>();
```

then doing;

```
  wordslist.Add(line.Split(' '));
```

to add items. `List<T>` is a dynamic array and will grow as necessary. `T[]` (an array) cannot grow dynamically and because of that is not a good collection choice for reading the file.

Here's another suggestion (how I would do it);

```
  string[] words = File.ReadAllLines(path).Where(x => !x.IsNullOrEmpty())
                                          .Select(x => x.Split(' '))
                                          .SelectMany();
```

That one liner will first, read every line of the file into a `string[]`, the Where is then applied and all of the empty lines are removed. After that each line is split on space which gives you an `IEnumerable<string[]>` (a list of string arrays where each array is a lines worth of words) and finally the `SelectMany` "flattens" the list meaning it combines all of those arrays into one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Linq`

```
var wordslist= System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("filename")
              .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
              .SelectMany(x => x.Split(' '));

foreach(var word in wordlist)
{
   Console.WriteLine("\ncapacity " + word);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand what you ask for, but it appears you want to read content of file without empty lines?
Your code is quite a mess, here you got little bit that will return all non-empty lines from file.

```
List<string> readIt(string fileName)
{
    string line;
    List<string> data = new List<string>();
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(fileName);
    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    { if (line!="") data.Add(line); }
    file.Close();
    return data;
}
```